# Wordpress - Website not opening and there are no errors

Tags: wordpress

I have a website on SHIVAPALACE.IN but it is not opening, the admin panel works fine but the front end doesn't open and no error is shown, i have tried to delete my .htaccess and create a new one but nothing works. only a blank page is seen. Can someone help me?

Thanks & Regards
Akshat

Comment: what is the log file says? thanks.

Comment: @FiidoFirdauz There is no log file that is formed. The wp-debug is enabled

Comment: is your website in on live?

Comment: @FiidoFirdauz Sorry dear didnt get you. Do you mean to say whether the website was online when this happen? if so yes

Comment: Try applying a different theme to see if it's a theme issue.

Comment: @MwcsMac but sir i have been using this since 8th october and there was no problem so how come now there is?

Comment: @Bhaamb follow my method, let me know if that method works.

Comment: @MwcsMac i tried to use the default theme but still nothing works

Comment: have u install any plugin?

Comment: @FiidoFirdauz i have disabled all of them

Comment: Before you made the change that now shows the Apache page is was getting HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden when using curl.

Comment: Post what you did to get he site up again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update 1.0**

Try this method.

1.Add the following code in your wp-config.php file.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true);
```

2.Disabling All Plugins

3.Increasing the Memory Limit

If all above didnt work. Then it is a strong indicator that your web hosting provider is having some issues

Comment: Then try contact your web hosting provider. Maybe their having some issues